# Tensorflow, tf.case() vs tf.cond() with logical operation

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have 2 tensors X, and Y.

```
X = tf.constant([[-1,-2,-3],[4,5,6]], dtype=tf.float32)
Y = tf.constant([[-2,2,2],[-2,2,2]], dtype=tf.float32)
```

The operation I want is:

if ((X > 0 and Y > 0) or (X < 0 and Y < 0)): X+Y
else: X-Y

I followed the sample at the [tf.case](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/case):

Example 2:
Pseudocode:

```
if (x < y && x > z) raise OpError("Only one predicate may evaluate true");
if (x < y) return 17;
else if (x > z) return 23;
else return -1;
```

Expressions:

```
def f1(): return tf.constant(17)
def f2(): return tf.constant(23)
def f3(): return tf.constant(-1)
r = case({tf.less(x, y): f1, tf.greater(x, z): f2},
         default=f3, exclusive=True)
```

The reason tf.case() wouldn't work is that the condition must be a scalar tensor so it wouldn't support a 2D tensor.

```
Each pair contains a boolean scalar tensor and a python callable
```

Tried with tf.cond() and failed:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([[-1,-2,-3],[4,5,6]], dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.constant([[-2,2,2],[-2,2,2]], dtype=tf.float32)

zero = tf.fill(tf.shape(a), 0.0)

def f1(): return tf.add(a,b)
def f2(): return zero

c = tf.cond(tf.less(a,b), f1, f2)

with tf.Session() as session:
    r_c = session.run([c])
    print (r_c)
```

Here is the error report:

```
    Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 2 for 'cond/Switch' 
(op: 'Switch') with input shapes: [2,3], [2,3].
```

Comment: What is the reason for not using [`tf.cond()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond)

Comment: How it's going to be done with tf.cond()?

Comment: Got a hint and will try tf.where(): In tensorflow > v1.0 tf.select replaced with tf.where and logical operations can be accessed directly like tf.equal. A sample loss function can be:
def loss(y_true, y_pred):
 import tensorflow as tf
 pt = tf.where(tf.equal(y_true, 1), y_pred, 1 - y_pred)
 return -K.sum(alpha * K.pow(1. - pt, gamma) * K.log(pt))